# Is it possible to set "no auto scheduling" when we update scheduling queries?

Tags: google-bigquery

I manage some scheduling queries of BigQuery in a GCP environment.

I wrote a following script to manage the scheduling queries. In this case, I expect that the configuration of existing queries will be changed when I build this file. However, the auto scheduling setting of the existing queries has not turned off.

```
targets="
query_1
query_2
"

for target in ${targets};do
  query="
      select * from testtable
      "
  tmpfile=$(mktemp)
  echo "{}" \
      | jq --arg query "${query}" '.query = $query' > ${tmpfile}
  query_resource=$(bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=${location} | grep dataset_${target} | awk -F "  " '{print $2}')
  if [ -n "${query_resource}" ]; then
    bq update \
      --transfer_config \
      --no_auto_scheduling=true \
      --params="$(cat ${tmpfile})" \
      ${query_resource}
  else
    bq mk \
      --transfer_config \
      --location=${location} \
      --data_source=scheduled_query \
      --service_account_name=${service_account_name} \
      --project_id=${project_id} \
      --no_auto_scheduling=true \
      --display_name="dataset_${target}" \
      --use_legacy_sql=false \
      --params="$(cat ${tmpfile})"
  fi
done
```

Does anyone know what the cause of this issue? I guess "--no_auto_scheduling" option is not supported when we update the queries, but couldn't find any document.